# Liferay portal 7.3.7 case insensitive, diacritics free with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, case-insensitive, diacritics, liferay-7.3

I am having a dilema on liferay portal 7.3.7 with case insensitive and diacritis free search through elasticsearch in JournalArticles with custom ddm fields. Liferay generated fieldmappings in **Configuration->Search** like this:

```
    ...
    },
    "localized_name_sk_SK_sortable" : {
      "store" : true,
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    ...
```

I would like to have these *_sortable fields usable for case insensitive and dia free searching, so I tried to add analyzer and normalizer to liferay search advanced configuration in **System Settings->Search->Elasticsearch 7** like this:

```
{  
  "analysis":{  
    "analyzer":{
        "ascii_analyzer":{  
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter":["asciifolding","lowercase"]
        }
    },
    "normalizer": {
        "ascii_normalizer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "char_filter": [],
            "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

After that, I overrided mapping for template_string_sortable:

```
     {
      "template_string_sortable" : {
        "mapping" : {
          "analyzer": "ascii_analyzer",
          "normalizer": "ascii_normalizer",
          "store" : true,
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "match_mapping_type" : "string",
        "match" : "*_sortable"
      }
    }
```

After reindexing, my sortable fields looks like this:

```
    ...
    },
    "localized_name_sk_SK_sortable" : {
      "normalizer" : "ascii_normalizer",
      "store" : true,
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    ...
```

Next, I try to create new content for my ddm structure, but all my sortable fields looks same, like this:

```
 "localized_title_sk_SK": "test diakrity časť 1 ľščťžýáíéôň title",
 "localized_title_sk_SK_sortable": "test diakrity časť 1 ľščťžýáíéôň title",
```

but I need that sortable field without national characters, so i.e. I can find by "*cast 1*" through wildcardQuery in localized_title_sk_SK_sortable and so on... THX for any advice (maybe I just have wrong appearance to whole problem? And I am really new to ES)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it would be better to apply `original_ascii_folding` and then `lowercase` filter, but keep in mind this filter are for search and your `_source` data wouldn't be changed because you applied analyzer on the field.

If you need to manipulate the data before ingesting it you can use Ingest pipeline feature in Elasticsearch for more information check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html).

Comment: THX, I'll try that, I don't need to mainly manipulate data, I just need to get data with national chars by its ASCII equivalent (so if I call wildcardQuery on localized_title_sk_SK_sortable with "*cast 1*", it should return data with "test diakrity časť 1 ľščťžýáíéôň title")

Comment: OK, through Postman, this solution is working, so my normalizer is written correctly and template is correctly overrided (maybe analyzer is useless here, because if I understand it correctly, it is not working on keyword type), THX for help